# List result not expected in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
input = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '6', '8'], ['0', '0', '8', '5', '7', '0', '4', '0', '0'], ['6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '5', '0'], ['0', '0', '6', '4', '0', '7', '9', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '4', '0', '8', '0', '0', '1', '6'], ['8', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '7', '9', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '8', '4', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '7']]

inputlock=[[False]*9]*9
for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,9):
        input[i][j] = int(input[i][j])
        if input[i][j] == 0:
            inputlock[i][j] = True
        else:
            inputlock[i][j] = False
```

And when run it : inputlock= [[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False]*9]

I think with this code inputlock[0,6] must be False. Why it true and why it repeat that 9 time
(This the my first post on there and my english not good) Thanks all !

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you take a look on [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to learn how things work here. Undoing edits, which clearly improved your question, just to maintain unreadability is clearly not how things work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the repeat operator on a list literal you're simply repeating the same reference to the same list, so in the end you're getting only the result of the last iteration.

So instead of:

```
inputlock=[[False]*9]*9
```

Use list comprehension to initialize inputlock:

```
inputlock=[[False] * 9 for j in range(9)]
```

Comment: So if i want use list in Python like array 2d in Pascal, i should code like that too?

Comment: @vĩkhangvõ Yes, you just have to be careful not to reuse a list reference when you mean to make it a separate list.